# How to migrate data from community edition(cloud) of Sonarqube to community edition(local)of Sonarqube?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am looking forward to migrate from Sonarqube community edition(cloud) to community edition(local). If this is possible, please guide us with steps and links for carrying the same. Also help us to configure multiple nodes in Sonarqube. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think this is possible? Have also a look at the [documentation](https://www.sonarsource.com/plans-and-pricing/). You can always start with an empty database (which means no history).

Comment: @JeroenHeier, Please read the description again. I have stated "If this is possible". I cant think of "Why this is possible". 
If you have ideas, please leave behind :)